# SQL query not returning expected results after LEFT JOIN (schema included)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I created a query earlier which concatenates staff members associated with a customer. There is only ever 2 customers assigned to each customer. My problem is after the query is executed, for each customer, it associates ALL staff members with each customer, not 2. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT C.customer_id, 
       C.l_name                         AS Surname, 
       C.f_name                         AS 'First Name', 
       C.travel_date, 
       T.tour_name, 
       Group_concat(S.f_name, S.l_name) AS Staff_Concat 
FROM   customers AS C 
       LEFT JOIN tour AS T 
              ON C.tour_id = T.tour_id 
       LEFT JOIN staff_day AS SD 
              ON C.tour_id = SD.tour_id 
       LEFT JOIN staff_day AS SD_2 
              ON SD_2.sd_date = C.travel_date 
       LEFT JOIN staff AS S 
              ON SD.staff_id = S.staff_id 
WHERE  C.travel_date >= '2014-07-08 00:00:00' 
       AND C.travel_date <= '2014-07-08 23:59:59' 
       AND C.customer_id NOT IN (SELECT O.customer_id 
                                 FROM   customers AS C, 
                                        orders AS O 
                                 WHERE  C.travel_date >= '2014-07-08 00:00:00' 
                                        AND C.travel_date <= 
                                            '2014-07-08 23:59:59' 
                                        AND C.customer_id = O.customer_id) 
GROUP  BY C.customer_id
```

I have tried using:

```
SD.staff_ID = S.staff_ID
```

in the where clause but didn't have much luck. I feel as though:

```
LEFT JOIN Staff AS S ON SD.staff_ID = S.staff_ID
```

is unnecessary but I can't seem to explain why. This is the results I'm getting:

```
6166    customer_Name   2014-07-08 Wildthing    Staff1, Staff2, staff3...staff10
```

my expected results should be:

```
6166    customer_Name   2014-07-08 Wildthing    Staff1, staff2
```

Apologies again if this is a duplicate. I did do some research but I'm at a dead end now.

following is DB schema:

```
Table structure for table Customers
Column  Type    Null    Default
customer_ID int(11) No  
f_Name  varchar(30) Yes NULL
l_Name  varchar(30) No  
address varchar(100)    No  
suburb  varchar(30) No  
state   varchar(30) No  
country varchar(30) No  
postcode    varchar(30) No  
email   varchar(50) No  
phone   varchar(20) No  
child_1 varchar(30) Yes NULL
child_2 varchar(30) Yes NULL
child_3 varchar(30) Yes NULL
child_4 varchar(30) Yes NULL
travel_Date datetime    No  
signature   text    No  
terms   tinyint(1)  No  
interested_video    tinyint(1)  Yes 0
specials    tinyint(1)  Yes NULL
tour_ID int(11) Yes NULL
updated timestamp   No  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Table structure for table Staff
Column  Type    Null    Default
f_Name  varchar(30) No  
l_Name  varchar(30) No  
comm_Value  int(3)  No  
staff_Type  varchar(50) No  
staff_ID    int(11) No  
bus_ID  int(11) No  

Table structure for table Staff_Day
Column  Type    Null    Default
sd_ID   int(11) No  
staff_ID    int(4)  No  
tour_ID int(4)  No  
sd_Date datetime    No  

Table structure for table Tour
Column  Type    Null    Default
tour_Name   varchar(30) No  
tour_ID int(11) No  
bus_ID  int(11) No
```

Comment: @PM77-1 Schema has been added

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server?  It's tagged as both...

Comment: @pmbAustin it is MySQL. Apologies

Comment: I suspect the second join to Staff_Day SD_2 is incorrect, the dates are excluded in the where clause - this will cause additional rows to be returned.

Comment: @simo.3792095 I have had my suspicions about this too. I just don't understand it enough. Only way for me is to do trial and error. Will keep you guys updated

Comment: second suspicion is that all JOINS are LEFT (some may need to be INNER JOINS).  Which means you may be joining directly across from Customer to Staff_Day and then Staff, and that there are NULLS for the Tour or similar.  If you comment out your current fields a return '*' you might see some anomalies in your data.  When I have these problems the best thing is to pull the SQL apart and rebuild it step by step ensuring you get what you want/expect at each step.

Comment: last suspicion is that your GROUP BY may need to specify more fields such as C.l_name, C.f_name, C.travel_date, T.tour_name.

Comment: @simo.3792095 Thanks for the tip. I'm going to go ahead and deconstruct my query and look in more depth on using LEFT and INNER joins.